# Receiving a notification without loading the view

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, viewcontroller, nsnotificationcenter

As I explained in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42463503/passing-data-while-dismissing-a-view), I'm trying to pass data from a UISwitch in a TableView to another ViewController. However, I want the data to be passed when the Settings View (which contains the UISwitch) is dismissed. Following the third step of this great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42463705/4805995), I'm using UserDefaults to pass the data and trying to use NotificationCenter to update the UserDefaults values when dismissing the Settings View.

> *To update when user defaults values change, you could have your Settings controller post a Notification when dismissing. Then, other VCs in your app could listen for this notification and update as needed.*

I've tried retrieving the notification inside viewDidLoad, but the value doesn't get refreshed because dismissing the Settings View doesn't load the new ViewController everytime.

How can I receive/read a notification every time the Settings View is dismissed? More precisely, where and how would I write the code for reading the notification?

---

Here's the code for posting the notification:

```
class SettingsViewController: UIViewController {

@IBAction func doneButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("nSound"), object: nil)

}
```

Here's the code for retrieving the notification:

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var testLabel: UILabel!    
    var savedValue = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "sound")


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.viewDidLoad), name: Notification.Name("nSound"), object: nil)

//refresh the savedValue variable       
        savedValue = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "sound")

//test the savedValue variable
        if (savedValue == true) {
            testLabel.text = "yes"
        } else {
            testLabel.text = "no"
        }

    }
```

Comment: Rather than having your Settings controller try to guess when other VCs are able to receive a notification, how about making the other VCs ask your data model for information when they need it?  ... `viewDidAppear` / `viewWillAppear` being possible candidates.

Comment: Already tried receiving the notification at viewDidAppear. But just like before, the view doesn't appear or load each time. It's always there in the background.

Comment: I said "ask your data model" not "receive notification".  Presumably, a VC only needs the data at the point where it updates the screen.

Comment: @Gabe12: can you post the code you're using to register for the notification?

Answer (score 1):

The variable savedValue wasn't refreshing itself each time I dismissed the Settings View. This is because the other ViewController wasn't loading itself each time. What I did is I created a new function that runs when the notification is called (which is when Settings View is dismissed). Here is the code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var testLabel: UILabel!    
var savedValue = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "sound")


override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.retrieveValue), name: Notification.Name("nSound"), object: nil)

//For when the view appears the first time
    savedValue = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "sound")

    if (savedValue == true) {
        testLabel.text = "yes"
    } else {
        testLabel.text = "no"
    }

}

func retrieveValue() {

//refresh the savedValue variable       
            savedValue = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "sound")

//test the savedValue variable
            if (savedValue == true) {
                testLabel.text = "yes"
            } else {
                testLabel.text = "no"
            }

    }
```

Note that *addObserver* now calls the function *retrieveValue()*.

Answer (score 0):

Using notifications won't work very well for this use case, and it's not necessary. I'll refer to the value of the switch as mySetting.

**MyViewController** (the view controller that will use mySetting)

- read mySetting from UserDefaults in `viewWillAppear(_:)` and use it

**SettingsViewController** (the view controller containing the switch)

- read mySetting from UserDefaults and assign it to the switch in `viewWillAppear(_:)`
- write mySetting to UserDefaults when a `valueChanged` event is triggered on the switch

Unless you present SettingsViewController in a popover, the `viewWillAppear(_:)` implementation of MyViewController will be executed when it's newly loaded as well as when you return to it from any other view controller.